# Format function strips php variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I am trying to pass parameters inside a string but for some reason the `format` function removes the variable part (`$data` and `$test`)

```
import os
import textwrap
def reformat(template):
    #return template
    return textwrap.dedent(template).lstrip()    
initial = "$data['completitions']   = [$test];"
scopes = 'meta.embedded.block.php, source.php'
tabTrig = 'doc'
template = reformat(
    """
    <snippet>
    \t<content><![CDATA[
    \t{0}
    \t]]></content>
    \t<tabTrigger>{2}</tabTrigger>
    \t<scope>{1}</scope>
    </snippet>
    """.format(initial, scopes, tabTrig))
v.run_command("insert_snippet", {"contents": template})
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    ['completitions']   = []; // NOTICE HERE
    ]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>doc</tabTrigger>
    <scope>meta.embedded.block.php, source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    $data['completitions']   = [$test]; // NOTICE HERE
    ]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>doc</tabTrigger>
    <scope>meta.embedded.block.php, source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it might be considering `$data` and `$test` as variables and resolving them as empty string. Can you try escaping each `$` with maybe `\$` or `$$`?

Comment: works, but how do I add this in the string, need to add it before `addslash().format`

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to add more context to this. If you print `template`, you'll see that `$data` and `$test` are printed correctly.

I don't know what `v.run_command` does, nor where `addslash().format` is.

Comment: I need to add to this side `""".format(ESCAPE_FUNCTION(initial), scopes, tabTrig))` a function to escape only `$`. v.run_command does not affect at all it's in sublime text.

Comment: ot smth like this `initial = initial.replace('$', '\$')` placed after the string.